# Is Intel MKL worth it for small vectors/matrices (2-4 D)

Tags: c++, vector, blas, intel-mkl

I want a fast vector math implementation for a video game. Even though I'll be working with 2-4 dimensional vectors 99% of the time, I'll be doing hundreds to a few thousands vector operations every frame (on CPU), so performance is important.

I've been considering Eigen and Blaze, because the benchmarks show that they are fast enough for what I want.

However, both of them recommend using Intel MKL for even better performance.

I know Intel MKL can be very useful for large matrices, but I was wondering how much of a difference does it make for small vectors?

Has anyone ever used it for such applications?

Comment: You could simply test it, MKL is available free of charge, just run a bunch of small operations through it and compare to whatever else you may be interested in. Eigen doesn't really make sense here since it's just a wrapper (and can use MKL in the background, depending on setup) - I might be wrong here that they implement something themselves for small cases, I don't know about that.

Comment: If you want the absolute best performance however, there are always ways to use the AVX registers efficiently, but you may have to write that yourself, depending on what the best approach to vectorisation is in your particular problem. I've been able to beat MKL by a significant margin in specific workloads, where you can use the knowledge of the full problem that MKL does not have access to. But this is tedious as you need to optimise for each CPU architecture and most likely not necessary for a game.